# One oven dinner

Tags: roasting

I have a ham that needs to be in a 275 degree oven for 2 hrs. My scalloped potatoes call for a 350 degree oven for 1 hr. Since I only have 1 oven, will the potatoes cook through at 275 if I cook them in oven for 1 1/2-2 hrs w/ the ham?

Answer (score 1):

The potatoes will probably cook through, but they most likely won't develop a nice golden crust, which would be disappointing.  Instead, I'd do the following:

1. Start the oven at 275° F
2. Roast the ham for 1 hour
3. Increase the oven temperature to 350° F
4. Cover the ham loosely with aluminum foil, which will protect it slightly from the increased heat
5. Add the potatoes to the oven for 1 hour
6. Pull the ham out about 10 minutes before the potatoes are done and let it rest, still covered with the foil
7. Extract the potatoes